# SQLAlchemy association data via related class constructor

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, associations

I have this design

```
# coding: utf-8
from sqlalchemy import Column, VARCHAR, ForeignKey, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import INTEGER, TINYINT
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.inspection import inspect
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy


engine = create_engine('mysql://root:toor@localhost/test', echo=True)
Model = declarative_base()
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()


class A(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'A'

    id = Column(INTEGER(unsigned=True), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(VARCHAR(32), nullable=False, index=True)


class AB(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'AB'

    A_id = Column(INTEGER(10, unsigned=True), ForeignKey('A.id'), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    B_id = Column(INTEGER(10, unsigned=True), ForeignKey('B.id'), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    type = Column(TINYINT(3, unsigned=True), nullable=False)
    A_rel = relationship(
    "A",
    foreign_keys=[A_id]
    )
    B_rel = relationship(
    "B",
    foreign_keys=[B_id],
    )


mapper_AB = inspect(AB)


class B(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'B'

    id = Column(INTEGER(10, unsigned=True), primary_key=True)

    As = relationship("A", secondary=mapper_AB.local_table, uselist=False)
    ABs = relationship("AB")
    type = association_proxy('ABs', 'type')


Model.metadata.create_all(engine)

a = A(
    name="test",
)

session.add(a)
session.commit()

b = B(
    As=a,
    type=2
)
print(b.type)

session.add(b)
session.commit()
```

This obviously fails, but I am trying to simplify the design by adding the AB extra information (type) via one (B) of the related classes constructor.

I have gone through tons of SQLAlchemy documentation, and even lost myself inside the source code but to no avail. The 3 table design of the database cannot be modified, as is part of a bigger system and belongs to another project. My goal is to map those table into a more simplified design for further development where this models will be used.

Is this possible using SQLAlchemy mechanisms with declarative style?